# How to get data without duplicate in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display data for students with many join tables in MySQL. But when I still got many duplicate student's data. This is my query

```
select
    `students`.`id`,
    `students`.`nisn`,
    `students`.`full_name`,
    `students`.`birth_place`,
    `students`.`birth_date`,
    `history_levels`.`is_processed`,
    `ls`.`mss_name`,
    `ls`.`msd_name`
from
    `students`
inner join `history_levels` on
    `history_levels`.`student_id` = `students`.`id`
inner join (
    SELECT
        learning_activities.id,
        learning_activities.student_id,
        m_student_statuses.name as mss_name,
        m_status_descriptions.name as msd_name,
        (SELECT name FROM m_status_descriptions WHERE learning_activities.status_description_id ORDER BY id desc limit 1)
    FROM
        learning_activities
    JOIN m_student_statuses ON
        m_student_statuses.id = learning_activities.student_status_id
    JOIN m_status_descriptions ON
        m_status_descriptions.id = learning_activities.status_description_id 
    GROUP BY
        learning_activities.id,
        learning_activities.student_id,
        m_student_statuses.name,
        m_status_descriptions.name
    ORDER BY
        learning_activities.id DESC
    ) ls on
    `ls`.`student_id` = `students`.`id`
where
    `students`.`institution_id` = 1
    and `students`.`deleted_at` is null
group by
    `students`.`id`,
    `students`.`nisn`,
    `students`.`full_name`,
    `students`.`birth_place`,
    `students`.`birth_date`,
    `history_levels`.`is_processed`,
    `ls`.`mss_name`,
    `ls`.`msd_name` ;
```

I got result from the query above like this

[image]

How to fix my issue?

Comment: Did you tried to use [DISTINCT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)?

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic how to use it? can you explain to me?

Comment: Check below and read tutorial that I posted to you.

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic I have tried it like your answer but, it's still duplicate

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Your rows are not duplicates.  You need to explain what values you actually want when there are multiple `mod_name`s for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your getting multiples because your mss_name and msd_name are all uniquely different, and as such by the group by will force one on its own row.  What I think you need is GROUP_CONCAT() which will group like columns into a comma separated list for whatever its group basis is.  Finally, you have in your subquery a select statement with no column name that does not appear to be used in final result set.  I would just eliminate that completely.

```
select
        s.id,
        s.nisn,
        s.full_name,
        s.birth_place,
        s.birth_date,
        hl.is_processed,
        ls.mss_name,
        ls.msd_name
    from
        students s
            join history_levels hl
                on s.id = hl.student_id
            join 
            ( SELECT
                    la.id,
                    la.student_id,
                    GROUP_CONCAT( mss.name ) as mss_name,
                    GROUP_CONCAT( msd.name ) as msd_name
                FROM
                    learning_activities la
                        JOIN m_student_statuses mss
                            ON la.student_status_id = mss.id
                        JOIN m_status_descriptions msd
                            ON la.status_description_id = msd.id
                GROUP BY
                    la.id,
                    la.student_id
                ORDER BY
                    la.id DESC ) ls 
                on s.id = ls.student_id
    where
            s.institution_id = 1
        and s.deleted_at is null
    group by
        s.id,
        s.nisn,
        s.full_name,
        s.birth_place,
        s.birth_date,
        hl.is_processed
```

Now, if you ever get multiple rows per student id within the history levels table, you might want to group_concat that and remove "h1.is_processed" from the group by.